# echo -e "word\b" not working as expected

Tags: echo

According to man:

> If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
>
> \b     backspace

So I would expect `echo -e "word\b"` to produce `wor` output. But yet:

```
$ echo -e "wor\bd"
wod
$ echo -e "word\b"
word
```

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Take a look at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5723935/6216002

Comment: Thanks, that explains it

Comment: @SantaXL, please don't post screenshots of text to stack overflow.  It would have been appropriate to copy the text from your terminal and paste into a text block on the site.

Comment: @DanielFarrell ok, will remember this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this can't be marked a duplicate of an SO question, I guess it's valid to put an answer here in U&L.

`\b` moves the cursor back one character, but it doesn't *erase* that character.  A final character printed would overwrite the character.

```
$ echo -e "hello world\bX"
hello worlX
```

Comment: So I guess that behaviour of `\b` can be summed up to: replace the previous character with the next next one. But since there is no next one in `word\b` (it seems to ignore newline), leave it as it is.

Comment: could be wrong but I think the newline doesn't hit the terminal the same way as `X` in my example because the terminal's in cooked mode.  You'll notice that if you type a command, scroll to the beginning or middle, and then hit enter, not just the part of the line left of the enter is sent; the whole command will be.    `\b` is best summed up as 'move the character back one cursor' .  It does _not_ replace anything automatically, but the next output to the terminal that isn't some special control character, if any, will end up replacing it.

Comment: Typing `echo -ne "hello world\b"` produces `hello worl`. `echo -e "hello\n\bworld"` prints `hello <newline> world` - it seems like `\b` does not work if the following char is a newline